# cakephp : session can't write

Tags: php, session, cakephp

If the Controller have the code `$this->autoRender = false;`
the session can't write.

```
function login() {
      $this->autoRender = false;
      $this->Session->write('Student', 'test');
}
```

Comment: how do you know the session was not written there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using CakePHP 1.3, You most likely have activated your Session Helper, but not your Session Component.  [Check the manual here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1310/Sessions).  You'll need both of these, probably in your AppController:

```
public $components = array('Session');
public $helpers = array('Session');
```

or PHP4:

```
var $components = array('Session');
var $helpers = array('Session');
```